# how can I test for ordered subset

Tags: python, pandas

***firstly***
I need to be able to test that `'abc'` is an ordered subset of `'axbyc'` and `'egd'` is not an ordered subset of `'edg'`.  Another way to say it is that it is an ordered subset if I can remove specific characters of of one string and have it be equal to another.

***secondly***
I need to compare one `pd.Series` with another `pd.Series` to determine if the elements of one are ordered subsets of the corresponding element of the other.

consider the `pd.Series` `s1` and `s2`

```
s1 = pd.Series(['abc', 'egd'])
s2 = pd.Series(['axbyc', 'edg'])
```

I need to compare them such that the results of the question
Are the elements of `s1` ordered subsets of `s2` equals

```
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: What you call an "ordered subset" is usually called a [subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subsequence) in math. See [this rather elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24017747) to the question [How to test if one string is a subsequence of another?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24017363)

Comment: @friendlydog thank you, I knew there had to be a better name for it.  I'm looking for better solutions than that.  I have one already.  I'm curious if others have better solutions.  I'll post my answer to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part of the question:

```
def ordered_subset(s1, s2):
    s2 = iter(s2)
    try:
        for c in s1:
            while next(s2) != c:
                pass
        else:
            return True
    except StopIteration:
        return False
```

For the second part of the question:

```
pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1).apply(lambda x: ordered_subset(*x), axis=1)

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 0):

use `'.*'.join` to create a regex pattern to match against sequence.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

s1 = pd.Series(['abc', 'egd'])
s2 = pd.Series(['axbyc', 'edg'])

match = lambda x: bool(re.match(*x))
pd.concat([s1.str.join('.*'), s2], axis=1).T.apply(match)

0     True
1    False
dtype: bool
```

---

Notice that

```
s1.str.join('.*')

0    a.*b.*c
1    e.*g.*d
Name: x, dtype: object
```

Comment: Interesting solution! For a general subsequence test, I have two suggestions: 1) use `re.search` instead of `re.match`--or prepend `'.*'`--to the joined string in order to allow the two strings to start with different characters (`"abc"` is a subsequence of `"zaxbyc"`); 2) if your strings can contain more than just letters, `map` `re.escape` over the first string to avoid clashing with regex meta-characters (so for example, you can test if `"ab*"` is a subsequence of `"zaxby*"`).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using a regular expression like that with Python's backtracking implementation, consider: `re.match('.*'.join("a" * 30), "a" * 30)`

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo I'm almost certainly going to abandon this approach for something else.  I'm trying to vectorize it.