# comparing two strings and their index seeing if all of string 2 is in string 1 with same order but different letter in between

Tags: python, for-loop

Assume all letters in the given words are lowercase.
You may use string methods if any are useful.

```
>>> occurs_within('aaacaabxyt', 'cat')
True

>>> occurs_within('tac', 'cat')
False

>>> occurs_within('oboe', 'bob')
False

>>> occurs_within('ecxbtalt', 'exalt')
True

>>> occurs_within('ecxbtal', 'exalt')
False

if len(word1) > len(word2):
    for i in range(0,len(word1)):
        if word2[i] < word2[i+1]:
            return True
        else:
            return False
else:
    return False
```

I tried using a nested for loop inside an if function comparing the two strings and looping to find if the next index of string 2 that is with in string 1 is greater than that of the previous index, but it turns out my result are all True somehow, and I cant figure out what seem to be the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test if one string is a subsequence of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24017363/how-to-test-if-one-string-is-a-subsequence-of-another)

Answer (score 2):

Walrus practice :-)

```
def occurs_within(s, t):
    i = 0
    return all((i := s.find(c, i) + 1) for c in t)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it **always** return `True`? I mean, str.find returns -1 on failure…

Comment: @Błotosmętek No, it returns `False` for example for `occurs_within('ab', 'ba')`. Not sure how you (and the downvoter?) misunderstand the code.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Not sure why this is downvoted. But this problem can be solved in `O(n)` time.

Comment: @Ch3steR Not sure why you're saying it like that. My solution is O(n). And probably quite fast, as it lets the string search itself (i.e., fast C code).

Comment: @HeapOverflow OK, I got it - `-1 + 1` is `False` :-) I guess I am not yet familiar enough with the walrus.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Hmm, I was kinda hoping you were the downvoter and would take it back after realizing the mistake. Not sure how my solution isn't useful.

Comment: @HeapOverflow `s.find` iterates through `s` until `i` in every iteration right?

Comment: @Ch3steR No, not *until* `i` but *from* `i`.

Comment: @HeapOverflow nope, wasn't me - I don't downvote unless I am absolutely certain the answer is wrong.

Comment: @Błotosmętek Your answer and heap's answer uses the same logic. But he incorporated it with walrus assignment.

Comment: @HeapOverflow In worst case say `string='aaabbcaat'` and `seq='uvw'`. `.find` searches the whole  `string` in every iteration right? Once take a look at my answer. Not telling to upvote my answer.

Comment: @Ch3steR Did a little benchmark, for the given examples our two solutions were about equally fast, but for `'a'*1000 + 'foo', 'foo'`, mine is about 100 times faster.

Comment: @Ch3steR yes, I know. What misled me was adding 1 to the return value of find immediately, so that the resulting value is 0 if find failed,

Comment: @Ch3steR No, in that example it would only search `u`. Since that fails, `all` will stop right away.

Comment: @HeapOverflow At this point I'm confused. Did the use of walrus assignment make your solution faster?

Comment: @HeapOverflow In my solution, I iterate through even if there's a mismatch. Your solution immediately breaks when there's a mismatch.

Comment: @HeapOverflow Better solutions deserve +1.

Comment: @Ch3steR Yes, although in my `'a'*1000 + 'foo', 'foo'` example that doesn't happen. Mine is faster than yours on that one because `str.find` is much faster than searching yourself in Python one char at a time :-)

Comment: @HeapOverflow Agreed. Hope downvoters retracts the downvote. Maybe the downvoter did not understand your code or misinterpreted it.

Comment: @HeapOverflow How can we rewrite this code in python-3.7 or less?

Comment: @Ch3steR Yeah, apparently it's easy to misunderstand :-P. At least the algorithm, and maybe also the usage of the walrus. I've written the exact same algorithm at least once before, so for me it's very familiar and this was literally just walrus practice.

Comment: @Ch3steR Previously I wrote it with a for-loop. Like Błotosmętek's but with the immediate `+ 1`. I guess `itertools.accumulate would work, too.

Comment: @Ch3steR Meh... I managed to write an `accumulate` solution, but it's ugly and it uses another 3.8 feature (the `initial` argument): `all(islice(accumulate(t, lambda i, c: s.find(c, i) + 1, initial=0), 1, None))`.

Answer (score 1):

To find if a word `word` is - for a lack of better word - "embedded" in a string `s` you need to find the position of the first letter of the word in the string, then the second letter in the remainder of the string (i.e. past the position of the first letter), etc. If at any stage you fail to find the next letter, you return `False`. This code does it:

```
def occurs_within(s, word):
    pos = 0
    for letter in word:
        i = s.find(letter, pos)
        if i == -1:
            return False
        pos = i+1
    return True
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's "rubber duck":

```
# if word 1 is longer than word two
if len(word1) > len(word2):
   # lets `enumerate()` or look at each index of word 1 , 
   # and see if it is in word 2
    for i in range(0,len(word1)):
        # if the letter of word2 at index "i" is less than
        # the letter of word2 at "i + 1" then return true
        #############
        # notice you're trying to compare using a relational operator "<"
        # which would be 
        # "a" < "a" == False 
        # "b" < "a" == False
        # "a" < "b" == True
        # for example:
        #     'oboe', 'bob'
        #     (w1 letter, index, w2 letter)
        #     o, 0, b < o == True
        #     b, 1, o < b == False
        #     o, 2, b < None
        #     e, 3, None < None
        # this doesn't work because word2 isn't alphabetical.
        # and the len() of word2 in these examples are not longer than     
        # word1. For example ["t", "a", "c"][2] and ["c", "a", "t"][2+1] 
        if word2[i] < word2[i+1]:
            # end the function by returning true
            # the loop will not continue to check the rest of the word
            return True
        else:
            return False
# word 1 is not longer than word 2
else:
    return False
```

see:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging
- [What does enumerate() mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22171558/what-does-enumerate-mean)

Comment: Why are your comments comparing letters from w1 and w2 at the same index when the actual code compares letters of only w2 and at different indices? And why are you discussing more than one comparison when there's a `return` after the first already?

Comment: @HeapOverflow thanks updated. see: `for i in range(0,len(word1)):` w1 index is being used to index w2.

Comment: Ah, I misread. Saw the `None`s now. What you call "w2 letter" is not really a w2 letter but a comparison, and it looked like a comparison of `word2[i]` and `word1[i]` to me. Doesn't help that the chosen example does make it look like that for the first two iterations :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex matching for that.

```
import re

def occurs_within(word1, word2):
    #build regex, basically inserting '.*' around any character in word2. In a regex, '.*' means any character any amount of time (even 0)
    regex = '.*{}.*'.format('.*'.join(list(word2)))

    #matching
    return bool(re.match(regex, word1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the first word letter by letter, if you find that the current letter is the one in your second string keep it and go on.

```
def occurs_within(str1, str2):
    index = 0
    if len(str2) > len(str1):
        return False
    if str1 == str2:
        return True
    else:
        word = []
        index = 0
        for letter in str1:
            if index == len(str2):
                break
            if letter == str2[index]:
                index += 1
                word.append(letter)
        print(word)
        return ''.join(word) == str2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Take **`O(n)`** time.

```
def func(a,b):
     a1=len(a)
     b1=len(b)
     i,j=0,0
     while(i<a1 and j<b1):
         if a[i]==b[j]:
             j=j+1
         i=i+1
     return j==b1
```

---

```
>>> func('aaacaabxyt', 'cat')
True
>>> func('tac', 'cat')
False
>>> func('oboe', 'bob')
False
>>> func('ecxbtalt', 'exalt')
True
>>> func('ecxbtal', 'exalt')
False
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested it with plenty examples of words and sub-words and this works for every one of them.

```
def occurs_within(word, sub_word):
    letter_at = -1
    for letter in sub_word:
        temp = letter_at
        letter_at = word.find(letter, temp + 1)
        if 0 < letter_at <= temp or letter_at == -1:
            return False
    return True
```

Basically the logic behind is that, in order for the function to returns `True`, you need to loop over `sub_word` and test, for each letter, if that letter exists in `word` and the index of the letter in that string (`word`) must be greater than the last letter of `sub_word` tested.