# Python: how many substrings in the given string contain given subsequence in time O(n)

Tags: python, string

The task is to calculate how many substrings in the given string contain the subsequence "tira". We need to find solution in time O(n). I have been trying to do this problem all day now and am losing my mind.

This solution works in time O(n^3):

```
import re

def count(s):
    pattern = re.compile('.*t.*i.*r.*a.*')
    result = 0

    for i in range(len(s)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(s)+1):
            substring = s[i:j]
            if pattern.match(substring):
                result += 1

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(count("aritaritaritaritarit")) # 48
    print(count("rtiraaar")) # 8
    print(count("ritari")) # 0
    print(count("taikurinhattu")) # 4
    print(count("ttiirraa")) # 4
    print(count("tixratiyra")) # 11
    print(count("aotiatraorirratap")) # 42
```

Comment: Couldn't you just count for each a how many r's are in front of it, for each r how many i's are in front of it and for each i the number of t's in front of that and then add them in a clever way?

Comment: Your first example contains 0 subsequences containing 'tira', but you say it has 48. So perhaps you can clarify what you mean by *subsequence*.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk means they're not necessarily consecutive but in order

Comment: A string contains a subsequence 'tira' when it is possible to form the subsequence 'tira' by removing some characters from the substring without changing the order of the characters.

Comment: Try a simpler problem first. How many subsequences contain "ta" ?

Comment: Have you looked at e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24017363/12846804?

Answer (score 0):

> *"... The task is to calculate how many substrings in the given string contain the subsequence "tira". We need to find solution in time O(n). ..."*

Traverse *s*, from *0* to *n−4*, checking *s[i:i + 4]* for *"tira"*.

Here is an example.

```py
def count(s):
    e = 0
    for i in range(0, len(s) - 4):
        if 'tira' == s[i:i + 4]: e += 1
    return e
```

Output

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: OP clarified in the comments his unique definition of *subsequence* and it's not the same one you're using.